# What is the scriptural source of the dhyana sloka of Lord Shiva given below?

Tags: shiva, identification-request, shloka

> “dhyayennityam Mahesham rajatgirinibham charuchandra vatansam
>
> Ratnakalpojvalangam parshu mrimgvarabhitihastam prasannam
>
> Padmasinam samantatstutamaganairvyagrahak- rirtim vasanam
>
> Vishvadyam visvsvandyam nikhilbhayaharam panchavaktram trinetram”

What is the scriptural source of the dhyana sloka of Lord Shiva given above?

Comment: This Dhyanam is the most used one in Bengali Puja manuals. I guess it is from some Tantras

Comment: @Rickross Any idea which Tantra?

Comment: No I don't know but it is the most widely used Dhyanam for Lord Shiva in Bengal.

Comment: I was watching Kashi Vishwanath live darshan one day and they were chanting this dhyana sloka, during Rudri Path chanting.

Comment: Looks like this is a dhyana shloka of Pashupati Astakam - https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_shiva/pashu8.html?lang=sa

Comment: @SwiftPushkar  Thank you so much my friend.  That should give us some lead!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is similar than the one below from **Shiva Purana**. (in this Shiva purana it is samantat sthitam and not samantat stutam like above) [**[śivapurāṇam : saṃhitā 1 (viśveśvarasaṃhitā) : adhyāyaḥ 20 : verse 52]**](https://sa.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A4%B6%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A3%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8D/%E0%A4%B8%E0%A4%82%E0%A4%B9%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%BE_%E0%A5%A7_(%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%B6%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B5%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%B6%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%B8%E0%A4%82%E0%A4%B9%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%BE)/%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%A7%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%83_%E0%A5%A8%E0%A5%A6):

> ध्यायेन्नित्यं महेशं रजतगिरिनिभं चारुचंद्रा वतंसं रत्नाकल्पोज्ज्वलांगं परशुमृगवराभीतिहस्तं प्रसन्नम्
> पद्मासीनं समंतात्स्थितममरगणैर्व्याघ्रकृत्तिं वसानं विश्वाद्यं विश्वबीजं निखिलभयहरं पंचवक्त्रं त्रिनेत्रम् ५२

IAST:

> dhyāyennityaṃ maheśaṃ rajatagirinibhaṃ cārucaṃdrā vataṃsaṃ ratnākalpojjvalāṃgaṃ paraśumṛgavarābhītihastaṃ prasannam
> padmāsīnaṃ samaṃtātsthitamamaragaṇairvyāghrakṛttiṃ vasānaṃ viśvādyaṃ viśvabījaṃ nikhilabhayaharaṃ paṃcavaktraṃ trinetram 52

[English Translation](http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/bitstream/10689/20655/4/Part1_Chapter2_81-160p.pdf):

> 52. He shall meditate on Shiva always in the following way:- He is like a silver mountain. He wears the beautiful moon, on his forehead. His limbs are resplendent with ornaments of gems. He holds the axe, the deer, the Mudra of boon and Mudra of freedom from fear in his four hands. He is joyful. He is seated in the lotus pose. The assembled Devas stand around him and offer prayers. He wears the hide of the tiger. He is the primordial being, the seed of universe. He dispels all fears. He is the three-eyed lord with give faces.

You can verify it from [Vedic Reserve](http://vedicreserve.mum.edu/puranas/siva_purana_01.pdf); go to  page number 135.:

> [image]

Comment: Thank you so much for providing an answer with much more than I asked.  Really grateful.